# match GSTIN number with PAN number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two numbers GSTIN and PAN

I want to match GSTIN number Starting later 3 to 12 it would equal to PAN Number.

it should generate an alert, if it doesn't match

For example

```
My PAN is : 1234567891

My GSTIN is : aa1234567891bbb
```

Then it is correct

**BUT**

```
My PAN is : 1234567891

My GSTIN is : aa7894561239bbb
```

Then it is wrong

I searched on google but cant find any solution, It is possible? Please guide me in right direction.

[image]

i tried below code with substr, but i cant able to get that value

```js
var pan = document.getElementById("pan");
var unino = document.getElementById("gstin");

var res = unino.substr(2, 11);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert( pan.value+'&'+res.value );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>PAN</label>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input pattern=".{10,10}" maxlength="10" required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan"  placeholder="PAN No 10 digist" value="" title="PAN Number must be 10 character"/>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>gstin</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="gstin" id="gstin"  placeholder="gstin" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var pan = document.getElementById("pan").value;
  
  var unino = document.getElementById("gstin").value;

  var res = unino.substr(2, 10);
  if(pan!=res){
    alert("Wrong GSTIN Number...!");
  }else{
    alert("GST Number is matched.");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
 <label>PAN</label>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input pattern=".{10,10}" maxlength="10" required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="pan" id="pan"  placeholder="PAN No 10 digist" value="" title="PAN Number must be 10 character"/>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>gstin</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="gstin" id="gstin"  placeholder="gstin" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated js chunk which would work for you. But this would only validate the lengths and if GSTIN contains PAN.

```
var pan = document.getElementById("pan");
var unino = document.getElementById("gstin");
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!(unino && unino.length == 15 && unino.indexOf(pan) == 2)){
        alert( pan.value+'&'+res.value );
    }
});
```

There should be regex validations also I suppose for the correct format of both in HTML.

The pattern for pan should be - `"[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]"`

That for GSTIN should be - `"[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}"`

Comment: how can we give "[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}" this validation to the textbox using javascript?

Comment: There is an attribute pattern which can be used straightaway. Else use validations on submission using RegExp as `var regex = new RegExp("[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]‌​{1}"); regex.test(input)`

Answer (score 0):

Just search for `PAN` string in `GST` string. if it finds `PAN` string in `GST` and index is 2 then there is a match. Otherwise NOT.

Hope that helps.

You can use `search` method as below

```
GST.search(PAN);
```

Comment: I want to match GSTIN number Starting later 3 to 12 it would equal to PAN Number, You can refer my uploaded image

Comment: @VishalPanara  If you use search, that is also same thing. It will give you the index if it matches and compare that index whether it is 2 then PAN matches with GST, otherwise NOT.

Answer (score 0):

## Pass Value To Function

```
//get value of StateCode / PAN Number / GST Number

var chkGstNum = checkGstNumber(stateCode, panNum, gstNum);
if(chkGstNum == 0) // Error Code
else // Success Code
```

## Function

```
function checkGstNumber(stateCode, panNum, gstNum)
{
    var GstateCode = gstNum.substr(0, 2);
    var GpanNum = gstNum.substring(2, 12);
    var GEnd = gstNum.substring(12,14);

    if(stateCode != GstateCode)
    {
        alert("Invalid GST Number.");
        return false;
    } 
    if(panNum != GpanNum)
    {
        alert("Invalid GST Number.");
        return false;
    }
    if(GEnd != '1Z')
    {
        alert("Invalid GST Number.");
        return false;   
    }
    if(gstNum.length != 15)
    {
        alert("Invalid GST Number.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```